# Params not passed in POST from bootstrap popover

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am presenting a list of training drills for a coach to browse. If a coach likes the drill then they can add it to their favourites. If a coach has more then one coaching assignment I am presenting a popover that asks them to select which assignment the training drill should be added to as a favourite.

The training assignments are presented as checkboxes, but when selections are made and the save link clicked I am not getting the checkboxes passed back my controller to process.

My popover is setup like:

```
 <%= content_tag :button, type: "button", class: "btn btn-default btn-xs", 
                 :data => { container: "body", toggle: "popover", placement: "top", 
                  content: "#{render partial: 'selectassignments', :locals => {activity_id: @assignment.activity_id, drill: drill}}"} do %>
     Favourite
  <% end %>
```

The renders my partial

```
<%= form_for(drill) do |f| %>
<strong>Apply to <%= Activity.find_by(id: activity_id).name %> assignments: </strong><br>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "drill[assignment_ids][]", nil %>
    <% assignments = Assignment.joins(:coaches).where('user_assignments.user_id = ? and assignments.activity_id = ? and user_assignments.role = ?', current_user.id, activity_id, "coach") %>
    <% assignments.each do |a| %>
        <%= a.name %>
        <%= check_box_tag "drill[assignment_ids][]", a.id, AssignmentDrill.where(drill_id: drill.id, assignment_id: a.id).exists?, id: dom_id(a) %>
    <% end %>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div align="right"><%= link_to "Save", drill_assignmentaction_path(drill, :add_favourite => drill.id), class: "btn btn-xs", method: :post, remote: true %></div>
</div>
```

My controller code is

```
def assignmentaction
  puts "processing assignment action"
  assignment_ids = params[:assignment_ids]
  puts "params[] array contains #{params.to_s}"
end
```

The console output displays:

```
Started POST "/drills/1/drills/assignmentaction?add_favourite=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-26 06:19:52 +1030
Processing by DrillsController#assignmentaction as JS
Parameters: {"add_favourite"=>"1", "drill_id"=>"1"}
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
processing assignment action
params[] array contains {"add_favourite"=>"1", "controller"=>"drills", "action"=>"assignmentaction", "drill_id"=>"1"}
```

I have whitelisted `:assignment_ids` in my controller and expect to see that POST'ed from the popover.

Not sure why that is not being passed?

Answer (score 0):

OK - easy fix in the end. Just read some of the documentation

I changed the form to `form_tag` and not a `form_for`

```
<%= form_tag(drill_assignmentaction_path(drill), method: "post") do |f| %>
```

and instead of `link_to` to submit the data is used a - wait for it `submit_tag`

```
<%= submit_tag("Save", class: "btn btn-xs", method: :post, remote: true) %>
```